# Page not found 404 No Blog matches the given query

Tags: python, django

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/like/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=UJ6I7mm2cjjSXK0MeuOLqm4E7OfMKTKtO461mCAsnTPdXT0UVw1z3JfMqijyIJAM&blog_id=
>   Raised by:    blog.views.like_post
>
> No Blog matches the given query.

---

I was making a like section for my blog app and this error is displayed below are my views, models and urls files

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Blog

class BlogsList(ListView):
    model=Blog
    template_name='blog/home.html'
    context_object_name='blogs'
    ordering=['-date_posted']



def like_post(request):
    post= get_object_or_404(Blog, id=request.POST.get('blog_id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(Blog.get_absolute_url())
```

---

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse 

class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField()
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.BlogsList.as_view(),name='blog-home'),
url(r'^like/$', views.like_post, name='like_post')
]
```

Comment: You check for a param `blog_id` sent with a POST method. The error says you've called the URL with a GET method. Therefore there can't be any POST request parameters. No blog could be found (`request.POST.get('blog_id')` is here probably either `None` or an empty string) and 404 NOT FOUND is returned.

Comment: Actually the underlying problem is probably in your template. It looks like you are submitting a form, but are sending it as GET instead of POST. You should show that template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view function `like_post` is the culprit here.

The `like_post` should be called with a POST method and passed a request parameter `blog_id`. I don't see where do you do this.

I suggest you to rewrite the view function:

```
def like_post(request, blog_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
    # the rest can stay unchanged
```

and in the `urls.py` change the following line:

```
url(r'^like/$', views.like_post, name='like_post')
```

to:

```
path('<int:blog_id>/like/', views.like_post, name='like_post')
```

Mixing the new `path` and the old `url` doesn't look very nice to me. Now you can pass the `blog_id` in the URL and the view will take care to return 404 NOT FOUND if a blog doesn't exist.